# Is there any known ranking of the most powerful telepaths/psionics/ psychics in the DC universe?

Tags: dc, psychic, powers

I recently came across a comic panel noting Jonn Jonezz, the Martial Manhunter, as "one of the most powerful telepathic minds on the planet", which falls in line with most data; Jonn has shown himself able to control others, create *completely realistic* allusions akin to genjutsu, and even link the minds of his Justice League teammates on earth from as far as the moon.

In the cartoons (**Justice League, Justice League Unlimited, The Batman, Batman: The Brave and the Bold,** and **Justice League Action** ) these powers aren't *usually* shown to their full levels; he's usually only shown mind probing, using telepathy,  or occasionally lifting others telekinetically. Other martians, like Meg'ann and Mal'E'fek, are shown to be somewhat on par with him, so martian brain power is well established, even if Jonn is noted as one of the strongest. Thing was, the toons tend to focus more on Jonn's *physical* abilities, like strength, flight and shape-shifting, more than his mental powers.

Despairo is noted as being a powerful psychic as well, capable of enforcing his will over armies.

Maxwell Lord was so powerful he could control the mind of Superman.

Matrix Supergirl was noted as having incredible psychokinetic powers.

And Brainiac's mental powers are often shown more over *machines* than people, but they are *quite* formidable.

Raven's psychic powers are immense, but effected by her emotions. They are also harder to gauge, being based in magic.

Generally speaking, however, DC comics and by extension, cartoons, tend to put less focus on their mental empowered heroes than Marvel comics do; "Mental Power" has been a category on most Marvel power scales for over 30 years. Their rankings also seem to be mostly consistent, with their top powerful "Psionics" usually being Professor Charles Xavier, mutants within the Grey/Summers family like Jean, Nate and Hope Summers, Emma Frost, Betsy Braddock, and other beings like Apokolyps (ancient mutant), Mephisto (demon), Game Master (omnipath), the Celestials (cosmic beings) or aliens from the Cree, Shi'arr and other races.

Not too long ago, DC published a list of its fastest beings, seen here:

[image]

There seems to be no "official" ranking for its "most powerful minds", though.

I was curious if there was a comic or source that could properly identify these characters and maybe even describe their precise abilities?

If no such stated document exists, anecdotal evidence could help.

Comment: Don't forget Gorilla Grodd!  Unless some recent re-re-reboot of the DC Universe pruned him off the psionic list.

Comment: @Blaze Good point; I forgot about him.

Comment: Did you mean "illusions" instead of "allusions"?

Comment: Can any1 tell me who's the guy behind Reverse Flash, holding what looks like a scythe in each hand?

Comment: @Nu'Daq I think it's Black Racer. https://dc.fandom.com/wiki/Black_Racer_(Prime_Earth)

Answer (score 1):

Unlike Marvel, DC Doesn't really use a scaling system for it's heroes abilities.
But [CBR](https://www.cbr.com/dc-telepaths-ranked-powerful/) keeps a good track on DC bests telepaths

1. Hector Hammond
2. Psimon
3. Raven
4. Manchester Black
5. Despero
6. Maxwell Lordd
7. Aquaman (controls entire ocean life)
8. Saturn Girl
9. Grodd
10. Martian Manhunter/Miss Martian

Comment: If you’re sourcing this from some CBR page at the very least you need to link it in your answer.

Comment: @Lazyreader Interesting list, although it looks as though you reversed it from what CBR had.

Comment: Not bad. What are the parameters of measurement for this, i.e. weight lifted telekenticially for strength? Distance or number of minds touched for telepathic range?  Full mental control and or erasure of memories for depth? Manipulation of other energies for variety? Basically, I'm asking what factor puts one person on this list above another, because while Raven may be able to produce more sheer psychic _force_ than say, Martian Manhunter, I have **never** seen Raven use telepathy to a level where she scans _every mind on the planet_ before. so logically, shouldn't jon be ranked _above_ her?

Comment: @Russhiro - OP has them in the wrong order. If you look at the blurb for number seven, it's clear that they're in *reverse descending order*. Also this list seems to be little more than clickbait. There's no system used other than the author's own personal opinion.